# Merge multiple objects' properties into one

Tags: swift

Let's say I have this class:

```
class Person {
    var firstName: String!
    var lastName: String!
    var phoneNumber: String?
    var email: String?
    var address: String?
}
```

Now I instantiate this:

```
let person1 = Person()
person1.firstName = "Nicolas"
person1.lastName = "Cage"
person1.phoneNumber = "999-999-999"
person1.address = "No 123, NYC"

let person2 = Person()
person2.firstName = "Nicolas"
person2.lastName = "Cage"
person2.phoneNumber = "123-1234-1234"
person2.address = "No 123, NYC"
person2.email = "nicolas@nicolas.com"

let person3 = Person()
person3.firstName = "John"
person3.lastName = "Travolta"
```

And I have this array:

```
let actors: [Person] = [person1, person2, person3]
```

How can I combine/merge duplicated persons where there is no conflicts, and also have the list of conflicting properties?

Expected property values of `Nicoals Cage` after merge:

```
Nicolas
Cage
phoneNumber -> Conflict
No 123, NYC
nicolas@nicolas.com
```

Comment: it's an mistake in this row `person1.phoneNumber = "123-1234-1234"` -> need person2

Comment: Please don't use implicitly unwrapped optional properties to avoid writing initialisers. If `firstName` and `lastName` should always be non-nil (as most people's names are!), then you should make them non-optional and write an initialiser for them.

Answer (score 0):

```
private func merge(actors:[Person]) -> [Person] {

    var uniqueActors = [Person]()
    var duplicatedActors = [Person]()

    //split actors into arrays
    for actor in actors {
        if uniqueActors.contains(where: { $0.firstName == actor.firstName &&
                                            $0.lastName == actor.lastName}) {
            duplicatedActors.append(actor)
        } else {
            uniqueActors.append(actor)
        }
    }

    //merge duplicated into unique
    for duplicatedActor in duplicatedActors {
        let uniqueActor = uniqueActors.filter({ $0.firstName == duplicatedActor.firstName &&
                                                $0.lastName == duplicatedActor.lastName }).first
        if let uniqueActor = uniqueActor {
            uniqueActor.phoneNumber = self.mergeProperty(valueOne: uniqueActor.phoneNumber, valueTwo: duplicatedActor.phoneNumber)
            uniqueActor.address = self.mergeProperty(valueOne: uniqueActor.address, valueTwo: duplicatedActor.address)
            uniqueActor.email = self.mergeProperty(valueOne: uniqueActor.email, valueTwo: duplicatedActor.email)
        }
    }

    return uniqueActors

}

//merge properties of 2 objects
private func mergeProperty(valueOne: String?, valueTwo: String?) -> String? {
    var isFirstPropertyExist = false
    var isSecondPropertyExist = false

    if let valueOne = valueOne, valueOne != "" {
        isFirstPropertyExist = true
    }

    if let valueTwo = valueTwo, valueTwo != "" {
        isSecondPropertyExist = true
    }

    var mergedValue : String?

    switch (isFirstPropertyExist, isSecondPropertyExist) {
    case (true, true):
        if valueOne != valueTwo {
            mergedValue = "Conflict"
            //here you can print or throw an Error
        } else {
            mergedValue = valueOne
            //random (equal values)
        }

    case (true, false):
        mergedValue = valueOne
    case (false, true):
        mergedValue = valueTwo
    case (false, false):
        mergedValue = ""
        //or you can return nil
    }

    return mergedValue
}
```

I think it can help you.
You can pass `func mergeProperty` into extension of Person class and `func merge` into extension of Array class where object is Person

Comment: Is this the most efficient approach? what if I have more than 3-4 properties and more than 2 duplicates?

Comment: it's just example of merge algorithm. if you have more properties - you just add one more line with mergeProperty. if you have more than 2 duplicates - it's working correct